# Formula for calculating rendering time for computer with 50% more performance?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assuming that all other factors are identical and there are no variations,
and 50% increase in performance on a computer is directly correlated to rendering time,
what would be the formula for calculating the reduction in rendering time?

I know that 100% performance gain (200%) would be 1/2 less rendering time.
But what would be 50% performance gain (150%)? 1/3 less rendering time?

Remember that 50% increase in performance results in a reduction of time.

i.e.

100% performance Computer A
150% performance Computer B

60 minutes rendering time Computer A
X minutes rendering time Computer B

I'm just trying to figure out how much renderng time generally I would get for a computer with 50% performance increase. For this math, we won't consider other variables, just to get a general idea with pure math, because I want to know how to use a formula so I can wrap my head around how to think about it.

I know it should be simple, based on the other questions on here (calculus, etc), should be easy pts

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is one specific problem. Solve for X and provide the formula

Comment: Hint: $Rt$ is a constant where $R$ is the rendering speed and $t$ is the time taken to render. We say $R$ is inversely proportional to $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh of course.

If 100% increase = 1/2 the time, then obviously

100%/200% = 1/2min

let a = original performance %
let b = new performance %
let c = a/b
let m = original minutes
solve for x

a/b = c
m*c = x

100/150 = 0.67

60 * 0.67 = 40 min